# How can I change the value of min word length for specific query in fulltext search?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I can set it a new value by adding this line under the `[mysqld]` section in `my.cnf` configuration file:

```
ft_min_word_len = 3 // or any other length
```

But I don't want that. I want to know, can I do that in a specific query? I have this query:

```
select * from mytable where match(mycol) against(:val)
```

And I want to change `ft_min_word_len` just for query above. I don't want to change it in MySQL configuration file. I mean I want to have another min word length for other queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:  Not possible.

Long answer...

That setting is used when any MyISAM `FULLTEXT` index is being built.  You should change to InnoDB, in which case `innodb_ft_min_token_size` is the variable to set.  (It defaults to 3.)

If you change the setting after the index is built, it has no effect on existing indexes or queries using those indexes.

The only way to change it is to (1) change it in `my.cnf`, then (2) rebuild the index on any table for which you want the new length.

Comment: As a note, this is how you can rebuild the index on a table: `REPAIR TABLE my_table QUICK;`